# using #define #ifdef for conditions

Tags: c

```
gcc 4.7.2
c89
```

Hello,

I have the following code that I am testing that will not modify the rtp stream.

```
#define DO_MODIFY_RTP
#ifdef DO_NOT_MODIFY_RTP
    if(modify_rtp_media_stream(channel->ipm) == FALSE) {
        status = FALSE;
    }
#endif
```

When I want to test the modify rtp stream I will set the `#define` to this:

```
#define DO_MODIFY_RTP
#ifdef DO_MODIFY_RTP
    if(modify_rtp_media_stream(channel->ipm) == FALSE) {
        status = FALSE;
    }
#endif
```

Eventfully this will be controlled by a property in a configuration file. But I am just testing both cases before I do that.

Does it seem strange to use `#define` like this?

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, you don't want to have to modify the source code, so you'd probably do something like this:

```
#undef MODIFY_RTP
#if defined(DO_NOT_MODIFY_RTP)
#define MODIFY_RTP 0
#else
#define MODIFY_RTP 1
#endif

if (MODIFY_RTP)
{
    if (modify_rtp_media_stream(channel->ipm) == FALSE)
        status = FALSE;
}
```

On the compiler command line you can have `-DDO_NOT_MODIFY_RTP`, or in a configuration header you can write `#define DO_NOT_MODIFY_RTP`, and the RTP stream will not be changed.  By omitting the definition of the `DO_NOT_MODIFY_RTP` macro, the function will be called and the RTP stream could be modified.

Or you can invert the condition so that the default is not to modify the stream:

```
#if defined(DO_MODIFY_RTP)
#define MODIFY_RTP 1
#else
#define MODIFY_RTP 0
#endif
```

The big advantage of the code shown is that it is always compiled — but the optimizer will eliminate the call to `modify_rtp_media_stream()` if MODIFY_RTP is 0.  This means that the compiler checks the syntax of the statement, so it doesn't get out of date as the code around it changes.  Debug code tends to decay if it is not compiled as the code around it changes but the compiler doesn't notify you of the problems because the preprocessor removed the code so that the compiler proper doesn't see it.

Comment: Just to add another further question. I have done the following for the compiler flags -D_DO_MODIFY_RTP to modify the rtp. And -DNDO_MODIFY_RTP for not modifying the rtp. And then modified this to #if defined(_DO_MODIFY_RTP) would that be suffice? Thanks.

Comment: Beware names starting with an underscore and a capital letter; they are reserved for the implementation for any use.  What you describe would probably work; it is perhaps more often done along those lines.  The trickiest bit is deciding what to do if both the positive and the negative macros are set.  You could generate an error (`#error`) or decide that one wins over the other.

Answer (score 1):

If the macro is going to used in other files besides that single one, I would advise against doing this.  If someone else is going to read the code - they'll have to navigate to another file to find what the macro is defined as.

`#define` is usually meant to replace text literals or constants that you will be using everywhere like 'true' or 'false'.  In this case, if someone uses this and "status" is not being defined or instantiated, it'll throw an error.

Personally, I would just call it a function and name it appropriately as to what it's doing.  Just have a function that returns 0 if false, or 1 if true would make it's usage clearer, and if someone else modifies the code less prone to ill-use.

If the project is large enough, you might forget what the #define is in six months, so think ahead and save yourself some pain.

Answer (score 1):

Test positive

```
#define DO_MODIFY_RTP
#ifdef DO_MODIFY_RTP // 
if(modify_rtp_media_stream(channel->ipm) == FALSE) {
        status = FALSE;
    }
#endif
```

Test negative

```
#define DO_MODIFY_RTP
#ifndef DO_MODIFY_RTP // 
if(modify_rtp_media_stream(channel->ipm) == FALSE) {
        status = FALSE;
    }
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

The method you propose is not standard at all. I had to look closely to notice the macros were different, because in that configuration they are usually the same.

This is more common:

```
#define DO_MODIFY_RTP
#ifdef DO_MODIFY_RTP
    if(modify_rtp_media_stream(channel->ipm) == FALSE) {
        status = FALSE;
    }
#endif
```

or

```
#undef DO_MODIFY_RTP
#ifdef DO_MODIFY_RTP
    if(modify_rtp_media_stream(channel->ipm) == FALSE) {
        status = FALSE;
    }
#endif
```